# Moving string's individual characters into array

Tags: excel, vba

There is a portion of my macro that tries to take a string and break down the characters into its own array value, as follows:

```
    'matchName As String is called from the Sub parameter

    Dim matchArray(1 To 30) As Characters
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1

    While Mid(matchName, i, 1) <> ""

        matchArray(i) = Mid(matchName, i, 1)
        i = i + 1

    Wend
```

From what I know, this should run perfectly fine, but I'm running into:

> runtime error '91': "Object variable or With block variable not set".

I honestly cannot figure out why this is the case and would love another pair of eyes (or more!) to see if I'm missing something.

Comment: `Characters` is not what you want. You want `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
Dim matchArray
Dim i As Long

ReDim matchArray(1 To Len(matchName))
For i = 1 To Len(matchName)
    matchArray(i) = Mid(matchName, i, 1)
Next
```

.

And while the above will work perfectly, this is more fun in one line and no loop:

```
myArray = Evaluate("transpose(mid(""" & matchName & """,row(1:" & Len(matchName) & "),1))")
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think about Len()... That was pretty silly of me haha Thank you very much!

Comment: I just noticed this, but is there a reason why you ReDim the array instead of simply coding "Dim matchArray(1 To Len(matchName))"?

Comment: I dim'd it as a Variant, so it needs to be an array before we start. ReDim does that. I hate static arrays and that's what you  get when you define the dimensions in the dim statement. Dynamic arrays are more useful.

Comment: Very cool, thank you for your quick responses, it's been a long time since I've done any coding and I recently got back into it for my job (sort of).